# How to find the index of header in csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Lets say I have a csv list like below:

```
 A   B    C

 aa  bb   cc

 dd  ee   ff

 gg  hh   ii
```

And I want to know what column, B belongs to?

In other words what command can I use to give me number 2 for the column that has B as the header?

Comment: post your initial code

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas as get column headers as a list, then use list indexing to get the position, from 0.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/csv.csv')

df.columns.to_list().index('B')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv` module from python, you must use the reader function to generate a reader object.

The reader function is developed to take each row of the file and make a list of all columns. Then, you have to choose the column you want the variable data for.

```
import csv
with open('data.csv','r')as f:
  data = csv.reader(f)
  headers=data[0]
  position=headers.index('B')    $1
```

**Note:** Index in Python starts from 0 not 1.